# Entity Framework Union And Paging

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the result query by running two queries and joining them with union clause. I have to use paging but I need results as inserted line. I don't want to order it again. But when I use paging I have to use order by clause. how can I get results with natural order.

```
var prodFullTextQuery = _db.Products
                            .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted
                                    && x.ProdStatusValue == (int)ProdStatus.Active
                                    && (x.ProdName.Contains(searchText)
                                        || x.Keywords.Contains(searchText)
                                        || x.ManufacturerCode.StartsWith(searchText)
                            ));

IQueryable<Product> prodQuery;

prodQuery = _db.Products.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted
                                    && x.ProdStatusValue == (int)ProdStatus.Active
                                    && x.VariantMainProdId == x.ProdId);

foreach (var s in searchText.Split(' '))
{
    var temp = s;
    prodQuery = prodQuery.Where(x => x.Keywords.Contains(temp));
}                           


prodFullTextQuery = prodFullTextQuery.Union(prodQuery)

//i need here by the order in which rows are inserted                           
var results= prodFullTextQuery
                .OrderBy(x=>x.OrderId) //i don't want this
                .Skip(prodCountPerPage * pageNumber)
                .Take(prodCountPerPage)
                .ToList()
```

Comment: You have to use `.OrderBy()` for paging. What do you mean _with natural order_?

Comment: i mean that i don't want to use any orders. i need just select's result. because my first query is exact words after that i split search keyword and i search again. but so if i use order by clause my rows order will be mix.